# Convert the airport codes into full airport names

Tags: r, lapply

I need to convert the airport codes to full airport names, for example, EWR/PVG as Newark/Shanghai using R. There is a package called 'airportr' whose 'airport_lookup' function helps in converting the abbreviations into full names.

```
> airport_lookup("PVG", output_type = "city")
[1] "Shanghai"
```

However, if I have multiple such entries, how can I convert all of such different codes at once. Will lapply come into use? I'm fairly new to R. I would be really grateful if someone could look into this problem.

I'm providing a sample dataset:

```
df8=data.frame("Student"= c("A", "B", "C", "D"), "Itinerary"= c("EWR/PVG", "PHL-YYZ/TPE", "GYE-BOG/MDE/JFK", "JFK/SCL"))
```

I'm expecting my result to give a new column with the full names of codes, something like below:

```
| Student |    Itinerary    |                                 Cities |
|---------|:---------------:|---------------------------------------:|
| A       |     EWR/PVG     |                        Newark/Shanghai |
| B       |   PHL-YYZ/TPE   |            Philadelphia-Toronto/Taipei |
| C       | GYE-BOG/MDE/JFK | Guayaquil - Bogota/ Rio Negro/New York |
| D       |  JFK/SCL        | New York/Santiago                      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R base `*apply` functions

```
> airports <- strsplit(as.character(df8$Itinerary), "\\W")
> cities <- lapply(airports, function(x){
    paste0(sapply(x, airport_lookup, output_type = "city"), collapse="-")
  })
> df8$Cities <- do.call(rbind, cities)
> df8
  Student       Itinerary                              Cities
1       A         EWR/PVG                     Newark-Shanghai
2       B     PHL-YYZ/TPE         Philadelphia-Toronto-Taipei
3       C GYE-BOG/MDE/JFK Guayaquil-Bogota-Rio Negro-New York
4       D         JFK/SCL                   New York-Santiago
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I have a doubt and it would be great if you could please clear that for me. What is the importance of splitting the string in the very beginning of your code? Is it possible to retain 'PHL-YYZ/TPE' as 'Philadelphia-Toronto/Taepei'  and not 'Philadelphia-Toronto-Taepei' (since we are changing the '/' sign to '-')?